# Running a Java Class which runs other class

Tags: java, powershell

I am using Powershell to run a script which updates a website by calling its main update utility class which calls other classes.
The problem is it runs the first Class (UpdateDBTableType1) but not the others.

If I run the class in eclipse it calls all Update Classes in sequence as expected.

What could be the problem?

Powershell Script:

```
java -classpath 'lib\*;.' UpdateWebsite | tee-object -filepath "F:\Java     Workspace\UpdateWebsiteOutput\log.txt"
```

Main Utility Class:

```
public class UpdateWebsite {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {       
          UpdateDBTableType1.main(arguments);
          UpdateDBTableType2.main(arguments);
          UpdateSiteMap.main(arguments);
          CreateImages.main(arguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that in production some condition is met in UpdateDBTableType1.main which causes the JVM to exit? Maybe an unhandled exception?

Comment: That was it. A jar I was referencing that Eclipse had but not in lib folder was triggering a class not found error. Thanks man!